# anchor tag is not getting created correctly

Tags: xslt

Hi i've the below xslt for creating anchor tags.

```
    <xsl:template match="para/text()">

<xsl:variable name="numx">
<xsl:number format="1" level="any"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="(contains(substring(substring-after(current(),'.'),4,1),')')  or contains(substring(substring-after(current(),'.'),4,1),'.') or contains(substring(substring-after(current(),'.'),4,1),' ')) and (contains(substring (current(),string-length(substring-before(current(), '.')) -1,2),' ')) and contains(substring(current(),string-length(substring-before(current(), '.')) -2,1),$numx)">


<xsl:variable name="before">
<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring(current(),string-length(substring-before(current(), '.')) -1,2))"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="NewN">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('0',$before)"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="after">
<xsl:value-of select="substring(substring-after(current(),'.'),1,3)"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="befdNumb">
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(current(),$before)"/>
</xsl:variable>



<xsl:variable name="aftdNumb">
<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(current(),$after)"></xsl:value-of>
</xsl:variable>


    <xsl:value-of select="$befdNumb"/>
<xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <a href="{concat('er:#CLI_CH_',$NewN,'/','P',normalize-space($before),'-',$after)}">

        <xsl:value-of select="concat(normalize-space($before),'.',$after)"/>
    </a>    
       <xsl:value-of select="$aftdNumb"/>
    </xsl:when>



    <xsl:when test="(contains(substring(substring-after(current(),'.'),4,1),')')  or contains(substring(substring-after(current(),'.'),4,1),'.') or contains(substring(substring-after(current(),'.'),4,1),' ')) and contains(substring (current(),string-length(substring-before(current(), '.')) -2,1),' ')">
<xsl:variable name="before">
<xsl:value-of select="substring(current(),string-length(substring-before(current(), '.')) -2,3)"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="NewN">
    <xsl:value-of select="$before"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="after">
<xsl:value-of select="substring(substring-after(current(),'.'),1,3)"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="befdNumb">
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(current(),$before)"/>
</xsl:variable>



<xsl:variable name="aftdNumb">
<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(current(),$after)"></xsl:value-of>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:value-of select="$befdNumb"/>
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <a href="{concat('er:#CLI_CH_',$NewN,'/','P',normalize-space($before),'-',$after)}">

        <xsl:value-of select="concat(normalize-space($before),'.',$after)"/>
    </a>

    <xsl:value-of select="$aftdNumb"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

but this xslt is getting applied i.e. the anchor tag is getting created if the text is like below.(having only '.' in the entire text).

serving on the company, by one of the means discussed at paragraph 12.012 below, a demand signed by the creditor

but i want it o be applied for the below text also

```
<para>the major issues here concern the notion of principal and ancillary jurisdictions, the ideal being that the ancillary jurisdiction will defer to the principal jurisdiction on most important matters, with a view to bringing about a just, practical and economically rational winding-up of affairs. A relatively recent development in connection with that ideal concerns the judicial promotion of court-endorsed agreements known as "crossborder protocols" between liquidators and similar officers appointed in different jurisdictions. It is important in this context, however, not to lose sight of the fact that certain matters of "administration" always remain governed by Hong Kong law. See paragraphs 12.016 to 12.032 below.</para>
```

please let me know how do i do it. i need to convert this number as er:#CLI_CH_12/P12-016 and er:#CLI_CH_12/P12-032

Thanks

Comment: Would it be possible to show your current XML you are using, and explain the logic behind the transformation? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @TimC, i've updated my query and sorry to sa that i can't show my entire xml document as it is very big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm quite sure there could be a better way dot this, but because it is not entirely clear what this xslt should do I stay with your solution.

**You need to do some recursive template calls.**
Change your current "para/text()" template to a named template with text as an parameter.
But replace every current() with $text

```
<xsl:template name="mytext">
        <xsl:param name="text" />


<xsl:variable name="numx">
    <xsl:number format="1" level="any"/>
</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="(contains(substring(substring-after($text,'.'),4,1),')') 
                          or     contains(substring(substring-after($text,'.'),4,1),'.')
                          or     contains(substring(substring-after($text,'.'),4,1),' ')) 
                          and (contains(substring ($text,string-length(substring-before($text, '.')) -1,2),' '))
                          and contains(substring($text,string-length(substring-before($text, '.')) -2,1),$numx)">
```

**....**

```
</xsl:template>
```

Add a new template to call the named one with the current text().

```
<xsl:template match="para/text()">
    <xsl:call-template name="mytext" >
        <xsl:with-param  name="text" select="." />
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

Add an `when` just before the `otherwise` to output the text before a not handled dot and call the named template with text behind this dot.

```
<xsl:when test="contains(substring-after($text,'.'),'.')">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,'.')"/>
    <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
    <xsl:call-template name="mytext">
        <xsl:with-param  name="text" select="substring-after($text,'.')"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
</xsl:otherwise>
```

Comment: hI @hr_117 this is working but only for the first number ('See paragraphs 12.016 to 12.032 below' here it is working only for 12.016), but not for the second number.

Comment: To make this work add a recursive call to the original when parts. Replace `<xsl:value-of select="$aftdNumb"/>`with `<xsl:call-template name="mytext">
        <xsl:with-param  name="text" select="$aftdNumb"/>
    </xsl:call-template>`

Comment: thank you verymuch boss this is working. u r genious. thanks again :-)